# Javascript code to open a new window not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have some code on my site that's supposed to open a new window when a user clicks on the link.

Everything works correctly in Chrome and Firefox, but it won't work in IE.

Here's the code I have in the page header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function popopen()
{
    newwindow = window.open("page.html","Title",'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=660,height=620');
}
</script>
```

And this is the code on the link:

```
<a href="javascript: popopen()">Click to open the popup</a>
```

How can I get it to work correctly in IE?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use `target="_blank"`?

Comment: I tried it on IE 9, but I'd like it to work on any of the current versions (I think XP still uses IE 8).
And I need it to open in a popup window, not in a new tab.

Comment: Have you tried changing it from `"page.html","Title"` to `'page.html','Title'`?

Comment: This is a pretty dumb question, but is IE blocking the popup?

Comment: Just tried that, didn't help.

Comment: No, seems to just not be working at all, I turned the pop up blocker off to confirm...

Comment: @Andre: `window.open()` is not the same as `target="blank"` and, in JavaScript, singe quotes are exactly the same as double quotes (unlike other languages).

Comment: Ah okay, I wasn't sure if using double quotes inside of double quotes(`href="stuff"`) would cause a problem.

Comment: Works for me as-is in IE6 and IE7. The error is either IE8+ or somewhere else.

Comment: Just updated the original post with the link to my site - if you have IE6 and IE7, can you try it?
The link is on my site - http://JewishMusicStream.com - click the pause button to stop the music from playing, and try clicking the link under the player.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the name of the window (JewishMusic Stream) **has spaces**!
(other browsers allow it, but IE 6, 7 & 8 don't)

you have at line 151:

```
function popopen()
{
    newwindow = window.open('http://jewishmusicstream.com/player.html','JewishMusic Stream','toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=660,height=620');
}
```

Should be:

```
function popopen()
    {
        newwindow = window.open('http://jewishmusicstream.com/player.html','JewishMusicStream','toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=660,height=620');
    }
```

Comment: Works great, thanks a lot!
And sorry Álvaro - I didn't dream that that had anything to do with it...

Comment: am i missing something? i seriously see no difference between the two code snippets....

Comment: @Nick 'JewishMusic Stream' (the top one) has spaces, the bottom one doesn't and works 'JewishMusicStream'.